# R plot, actual Row values instead of row numbers

Tags: r, time-series, scatter-plot, name-value

I have a data set containing names of Solar Panel arrays, their dates of completion and location (long/lat).

I created an rplot with the time of completion on the x axis and the names of each array on the y axis.
Here in lies the problem - the actual names are not displayed but the number designation for each row is. Is there a way to get the names listed on the y axis instead of the numbers?
![Names are supposed to show on the y axis, the years show up fine on the x axis]

Heres the code I used to make my rplot:

```
plot(solar$Year.completed, solar$Name, xlim=c(1990, 2025))
```

I am also considering making adding more granularity (if that's even a word to the x axis)

Thanks to whomever can help with this.

Here is what the plot looks like:

[image: Here is what the plot looks like:]

Comment: quick tip to improve the chances of a quick answer, it makes it smoother for people to help if you make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) then people don't have to go to the trouble of generating data to show how it may be accomplished.

Comment: Take a look at the examples in [`?axis`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/axis.html)

Comment: Also look at http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

Comment: I don't think I understand what the *"names"* are meant to be on the y-axis. Can you at least show us what `solar$Name` looks like? If they are not continuous data but character names then this plot seems a bit strange...

Comment: Are you asking for a bar chart oriented horizontally?

Comment: Here's a short list of the names returned when I type in solar$Name:
  [1] Alamosa WTF                                            
  [2] Arvada Ralston Water Treatment Plant                   
  [3] Rifle Pump Station                                     
  [4] NREL Mesa Top PV Project                               
  [5] Pima County Wastewater                                 
  [6] The North Face                                         
  [7] Western Riverside County Regional Wastewater Authority 
  [8] Inlands Empire Utility Solar Farm

Comment: The names are part of a list of Solar Panel arrays. the corresponding dates include the year each project has/will be completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup as everyone says, it's a lot easier if you can include data. But probably what you want is this:

```
plot(solar$Year.completed, solar$Name, xlim=c(1990, 2025), yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=1:length(unique(solar$Name)), labels=unique(solar$Name), cex.axis=0.5, las=2)
```

in the first line, yaxt="n" gets rid of the default y axis labels

the second line creates a series of points for each unique value of solar$Name

2 (first argument) means it's the y axis

cex.axis reduces the font size (because it looks like you have a lot of points)

las-2 makes the labels perpendicular (again you probably need the space)

and if you want granularity on the x-axis, you can do something similar (i.e. add xaxt="n" and create a custom x axis:

```
plot(solar$Year.completed, solar$Name, xlim=c(1990, 2025), yaxt="n", xaxt="n")
axis(2, at=1:length(unique(solar$Name)), labels=unique(solar$Name), cex.axis=0.5, las=2)
axis(1, at=1990:2025, labels=1990:2025, cex.axis=0.7, las=2)
```

Comment: Wouldn't  `barchart(stuff, horiz=TRUE)` be easier?

Comment: That was my first attempt it worked perfectly, however it made it seem as though all of the projects started from at the same time. I'll make sure to add my data next time I post a question.

Comment: I'm pretty new to working in R and with data sets overall - the help is very much appreciated.